# Colocar um valor do react junto com html em um a href

Tags: javascript, html, react

Boa noite, fiquei um tempo parado e estou com dificuldades para lembrar um pouco sobre o react.
Eu tenho um código assim

```
{users.map((user) => (
<tr className='trdata'>
  <td> {user.usuario_id} </td>
  <td> {user.usuario_primeiro_nome} {user.usuario_sobrenome} </td>
  <td> {user.usuario_email} </td>
  <td><a href='usersedit/{user.usuario_id}' ><AiOutlineEdit /></a> <a href='#'><AiOutlineSave/</a></td>
</tr>
))
}
```

Eu gostaria de colocar no href essa informação que tenho no id, mas desta forma não vai, se eu coloco somente  ele me encaminha a id certa, mas preciso ir pra usersedit/id.

Se precisarem de mais informações sobre o código só avisar. Obrigado

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Seu código retornará uma string "usersedit/{user.usuario_id}" pois está sendo passado como uma string para o href, ao invés disso use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para concatenar a string com seu valor de ID, um exemplo disso ficaria assim:

```
<a href={`usersedit/${user.usuario_id`}>Ir para página</a>
```

Ou caso não queira usar template literals, pode concatenar normalmente como a forma abaixo

```
<a href={'usersedit/' + user.usuario_id}>Ir para página</a>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Opa deu certo amigo, concatenar, era essa palavra que estava me faltando, muito tempo sem mexer rs, muito obrigado aí